# How do I get Active Directory Dynamic Distribution Groups using PrincipalContext?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

Writing a vb.net application that needs to display a list of Active Directory Dynamic Distribution Groups. The code below works when retrieving a list of groups - but returns nothing when I add the OU=DynamicDistributionGroups to the context definition. Can Dynamic Distribution Groups be obtained using the GroupPrincipal this way? Suggestions are welcome? Thanks

```
Using ctx As New PrincipalContext 
(ContextType.Domain, "MYLAN", "OU=DynamicDistributionGroups,OU=Email   
Groups,DC=mylan,DC=ac,DC=mycompany,DC=com")

 Dim pGroup As New GroupPrincipal(ctx)
 pGroup.Name = "*"
 Dim pSearcher As New PrincipalSearcher()
 pSearcher.QueryFilter = pGroup
 Dim results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = pSearcher.FindAll()
 For Each p As Principal In results
   listGroup.Items.Add(p.ToString())
 Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task using DirectorySearcher rather than Principal Context as follows:

```
Dim results As SearchResultCollection
Dim srch As New DirectorySearcher("LDAP://MYLAN/OU=DynamicDistributionGroups,OU=Email     
Groups,DC=mylan,DC=ac,DC=mycompany,DC=com")
srch.Filter = "(objectClass=msExchDynamicDistributionList)"
srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
srch.PageSize = 1000
results = srch.FindAll()
For Each result As SearchResult In results
    Dim props As ResultPropertyCollection = result.Properties
    For Each propName As String In props.PropertyNames
        Dim groupName As String = props(propName)(0)
    Next
Next
```